# Python Visual Studio code import Syntax problems // color

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax, colors

For some reasons my Visual Studio code doesn´t show the color for the imported library.

In the attached file you see what I mean.

I tried already:

- Deinstalled vsc and reinstalled it again
- deleted the settings.json in (%APPDATA%\Code\User)
- deinstalled all extensions and reinstalled it again

If you know how I can fix it, let me know it.:)

This picture shows my current vsc without any colors anymore

[image: This picture shows my current vsc without any colors anymore]

This picture shows vsc how it should be colored

[image: This picture shows vsc how it should be colored]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to in the image. Note though that `sleep` doesn't return anything, so `timer` will always be `None`.

Comment: If you mean that the text of some code does not have the right color, then maybe you can try another linter?

Comment: what do you mean with another linter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with the newest update of VSCode. [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125963) is a bug report showing the same problems. Changing linters seems not to fix the issue at the moment. [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_57) are the patch notes as well, even though they aren't helpful here. I suggest downgrading VSCode if you want to fix this issue, which may require you to first uninstall it and then reinstall from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56). Hopefully they will post a statement on this issue soon for a more permanent fix.

This issue has been fixed in the newest update of the Python extension. [Link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125963#issuecomment-859161693). Restart VSCode, navigate to the extensions page, and click reload on the Python extension.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is still there.
I disabled C/C++ themes.

After that I am able to see Python imports in color

[image]